# Fetch log streams manually from Nginx Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, logging, containers

I'm aware one can fetch container logs using docker logs, but how does Docker do it under the hood? How can I log the stderr/stdout streams manually e.g. in the case of Nginx container? I'm also aware that I can configure Nginx to output those logs as non-streams, but I'm curious how it could be done the other way.
Initially I thought maybe simple `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` inside the container would do it, but no.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Docker logs using the Docker API. Specifically using the `/containers/{id}/logs` REST endpoint.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerLogs

As for the Nginx logs, the 'docker way' to handle them is to redirect them to stdout so they turn up in the Docker log. The official Nginx images do this by linking the logfiles to stdout and stderr using the commands

```
ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

which you can see in the dockerfile here: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f3fe494531f9b157d9c09ba509e412dace54cd4f/mainline/debian/Dockerfile

If you're using the official nginx images, this is also why you can't list the nginx logs from inside the container.

Comment: Thanks. That should be helpful, but there's still the question of what does the Docker log collector do. I see the symbolic links in the log folder inside the container, but I'm unable to fetch data through them.

Comment: Are you asking how Docker captures the logs from the code inside the container? It does that by intercepting the system calls made in the container. For the logs, my guess is that it intercepts the Unix `write` system call. Then it takes whatever was written and stores in its log buffer.

Comment: I was wondering whether Docker was doing something similar to `tail -f` and/or if I could emulate what Docker does with bash commands. I hope I'm making sense. I kinda assumed that I failed to access the log streams because of Docker, but I'm not 100% sure anymore.